# In Angularjs Error : You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

when the 2nd time come to map page error displaying.You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.

here is my code.

In HTML

```
<div id="googleMap" style="width: 100%;height:500px;"></div>
```

In state js

> .state("restricted.ntrack.manage-route",{url:"/manage-route",templateUrl:'app/components/ntrack/manage-route/manage-route.html', resolve:{deps['$ocLazyLoad',function($ocLazyLoad){return $ocLazyLoad.load(['lazy_parsleyjs','app/components/ntrack/manage-route/routeDetails.js',"js!http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBEv2lW0vZjUHl5eMyqoUfT1xLVOFMwGlU&sensor=false&libraries=places,geometry&language=en",'js!https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/master/markerwithlabel/src/markerwithlabel.js','lazy_google_maps',]);}],},data:{pageTitle:'Create Route'}})

In js controller

```
function getValues() {
    // Assign empty array for model, start waypoints and distnation WayPoint
    $scope.manageRoute = {};
    $scope.originWayPoint = [];
    $scope.distnationWayPoint = [];
    // Assign the empty array for model value
    $scope.routes = []; 
    // Ajax url passed in get method to get the needed route values
    rest.path = 'manage-routes/read-route';
    rest.get().success(function (result) {
        // allocating dependency datas to respective models
        $scope.routes = result;
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        var flightPlanCoordinates = [];
        // Assign the google map infowindow to new variable
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        // Assign a map option
        var mapOptions = {
            myTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapOptions);
        // Iterate the loop to get location & route details to diaply in map
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.routes.length; i++) {
            var routeName = $scope.routes[i].route_name;

            if (($scope.routes[i].start_latitude != null) && ($scope.routes[i].start_longitude != null)) {
                $scope.locationDetails = [];
                // Assign array of latitude and longitude of orign to new variable
                var origin = [$scope.routes[i].start_latitude, $scope.routes[i].start_longitude];
                // Assign name of orign to new variable
                var originName = $scope.routes[i].start_point;
                // Assign array of latitude and longitude of destination to new variable
                var destination = [$scope.routes[i].destination_latitude, $scope.routes[i].destination_longitude];
                // Assign name of destination to new variable
                var destinationName = $scope.routes[i].destination_point;
                // Assign passenger count to new variable
                var totalPassenger = $scope.routes[i].total_passenger;
                // Iterate the loop to get waypoint location & route details to diaply in map
                for(var j = 0; j < $scope.routes[i].stop_details.length;j++) {
                    if (($scope.routes[i].stop_details[j].latitude != null) && ($scope.routes[i].stop_details[j].longitude != null)) {
                        // Push the vale to the array variable
                        $scope.locationDetails.push({'location':
                            $scope.routes[i].stop_details[j].latitude+
                            ','+$scope.routes[i].stop_details[j].longitude+
                            ','+$scope.routes[i].stop_details[j].location+
                            ','+$scope.routes[i].stop_details[j].passenger_count+
                            ','+$scope.routes[i].stop_details[j].stop_time+
                            ','+$scope.routes[i].stop_details[j].stop_distance
                        });
                        var wayPointDetails = $scope.locationDetails;
                    }
                }

                // Assign waypoints latitude and longitude of destination to new variable
                var waypoints = $scope.routes[i].lat_lang;
                // Generate random color to the route
                var random_color = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
                // Call a function to display marker & way to the user in map
                calcRoute(routeName,origin,destination,waypoints,originName,destinationName,totalPassenger,wayPointDetails,random_color);   
            }
        }

        function pinSymbol(color) {
            return {
                path: 'M 0,0 C -2,-20 -10,-22 -10,-30 A 10,10 0 1,1 10,-30 C 10,-22 2,-20 0,0 z',
                fillColor: color,
                fillOpacity: 1,
                strokeColor: '#000',
                strokeWeight: 2,
                scale: 2
            };
        }

        //function for claculate the route distance
        function calcRoute(routeName,origin, destination, waypoints, originName, destinationName,totalPassenger, wayPointDetails, strokecolor){
            //variable declaration for map
            var request = {
                origin : new google.maps.LatLng(origin[0],origin[1]),
                destination : new google.maps.LatLng(destination[0],destination[1]),
                waypoints : waypoints,
                travelMode : google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
            };
            var firstStop = wayPointDetails[0].location.split(',');
            var firstStopLatLng = firstStop[0]+','+firstStop[1];
            var originLatLng = origin[0]+','+origin[1];
            if (originLatLng != firstStopLatLng) {
                // Custom marker with more than one char for origin
                var originMarker = new MarkerWithLabel({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(origin[0],origin[1]),
                    map: map,
                    draggable: false,
                    raiseOnDrag: false,
                    labelContent: "START",
                    labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(15, 65),
                    labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
                    labelInBackground: false,
                    icon: pinSymbol(strokecolor)
                });
                // Display the details in map marker
                google.maps.event.addListener(originMarker, 'click', (function(originMarker, i) {
                    return function() {
                        /*if (originLatLng == firstStopLatLng) {
                        var originDescription = "Route Name : "+routeName+"<br>Stop Name :"+firstStop[2]+"<br>Total Passenger : "+totalPassenger+"<br>Passenger Count : "+firstStop[3]+
                        "<br>Time : "+firstStop[4]+"<br>Distance : "+firstStop[5];
                        } else {*/
                        var originDescription = "Route Name : "+routeName+"<br>Origin : "+originName+"<br>Total Passenger : "+totalPassenger;
                        /*}*/
                        infowindow.setContent(originDescription);
                        infowindow.open(map, originMarker);
                    }
                })(originMarker, i));
            }

            var lastStop = wayPointDetails[wayPointDetails.length-1].location.split(',');
            var lastStopLatLng = lastStop[0]+','+lastStop[1];
            var destinationLatLng = destination[0]+','+destination[1];

            if (destinationLatLng != lastStopLatLng) {
                // Custom marker with more than one char for destination
                var destMarker = new MarkerWithLabel({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(destination[0],destination[1]),
                    map: map,
                    draggable: false,
                    raiseOnDrag: false,
                    labelContent: "END",
                    labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(15, 65),
                    labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
                    labelInBackground: false,
                    icon: pinSymbol(strokecolor)
                });

                // Display the details in map marker
                google.maps.event.addListener(destMarker, 'click', (function(destMarker, i) {
                    return function() {
                        infowindow.setContent("Route Name : "+routeName+"<br>Destination :"+destinationName+"<br>Total Passenger : "+totalPassenger);
                        infowindow.open(map, destMarker);
                    }
                })(destMarker, i));
            }

            // Assign the google map infowindow to new variable
            var infowindow =  new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: ""
            });

            // Iterate the loop to get waypoint location & details to diaply in map
            for (var waypointsMarker = 0; waypointsMarker < wayPointDetails.length ; waypointsMarker++) {
                var splitLatLng = wayPointDetails[waypointsMarker].location.split(',');
                if ((waypointsMarker == 0) && (originLatLng == firstStopLatLng)) {
                    var labelContentName = "START";
                    var description = "Route Name : "+routeName+"<br>Stop Name :"+splitLatLng[2]+"<br>Total Passenger : "+totalPassenger+
                    "<br>Passenger Count : "+splitLatLng[3]+
                    "<br>Time : "+splitLatLng[4]+"<br>Distance : "+splitLatLng[5];
                } else if ((waypointsMarker == (wayPointDetails.length-1)) && (destinationLatLng == lastStopLatLng)) {
                    var labelContentName = "END";
                    var description = "Route Name : "+routeName+"<br>Stop Name :"+splitLatLng[2]+"<br>Total Passenger : "+totalPassenger+
                    "<br>Passenger Count : "+splitLatLng[3]+
                    "<br>Time : "+splitLatLng[4]+"<br>Distance : "+splitLatLng[5];
                } else {
                    var labelContentName = splitLatLng[2].slice(0,4);
                    var description = "Route Name : "+routeName+"<br>Stop Name :"+splitLatLng[2]+"<br>Passenger Count : "+splitLatLng[3]+
                      "<br>Time : "+splitLatLng[4]+"<br>Distance : "+splitLatLng[5];
                }

                var waypointsMarkers = new MarkerWithLabel({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(splitLatLng[0],splitLatLng[1]),
                    map: map,
                    draggable: false,
                    raiseOnDrag: false,
                    labelContent: labelContentName,
                    labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(15, 65),
                    labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
                    labelInBackground: false,
                    icon: pinSymbol(strokecolor)
                });
                wayPointsInfoWindow(waypointsMarkers, map, infowindow, description);
            }

            // Function used to display details of the location when click the marker in map
            function wayPointsInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, description) {
                marker.addListener('click', function() {
                    infowindow.setContent(description);
              infowindow.open(map, this);
                });
            }

            //declare route for the map
            directionsService.route(request,function(response,status) {
                if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK){      //if map orute is set
                    // directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);   //display the map
                    new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
                        map: map,
                        directions: response,
                        draggable:false,
                        polylineOptions: {
                            strokeColor: strokecolor
                        },
                        suppressMarkers : true,
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }).error(function(data) {
        // If any issue in loading data thown an error message
        UIkit.modal.alert("We are fixing a temporary technical issue. We will be back shortly. Please try again in some time(NETWORK ERROR)");
    });
}
```